# how to give regards to someone

Tags: phrase-request, greetings

I have been told by a (male) person A to give his regards to a (male) person B. I don't know them too well, but I have met them both semi-privately (person A is a coworker of a friend of mine and we have spent a day hiking; person B is an ex-coworker of mine and we had lunch together every now and then), so there is no need to be too formal. They know each other as (ex-)colleagues as well.

**How do I do that?**

Here are some thoughts of mine; please comment on their correctness, commonness and level of formality/informality. Please also give suggestions.

"Hello B, ...

1. "... best regards from A!"
2. "... I am supposed to send A's regards to you!"
3. "... hello from A!"
4. "... I met A recently and he told me to say hi to you from him!"

Answer (score 1):

They seem okay, but there are better options. For 4, I prefer *for him* instead of *from him* since *for* is used when you do something on someone else's behalf.

Anyway, two more idiomatic phrases, in my opinion, are

> 1. A sends his regards.
>      Example: I met A recently and he sends his regards.
> 2. A says hello.
>      Example: I met A recently and he says hello.

1 sound more formal. 2 is casual. As J.R. points out, 1 could be too formal for some everyday conversations. Considering your situation, I think they are both possible. If you want to sound more casual or friendly, use 2.

Comment: I'd add that "sends his regards" sounds more formal, and perhaps almost _too_ formal for some everyday conversations.

Comment: Somewhat related: to me, "I met A recently" sounds like you just met them for the first time. That could be right, I guess, if you are just meeting B's friend and finding out that they know B. But otherwise I might say "I met up with A recently" or "I saw A recently" or "I talked to A recently" or whatever.

Answer (score -1):

Item 1 might be ok in a letter. I would nix 2 and 3. 4 looks the best, but I would change it:  "... I met A recently and he asked me to send you his best wishes!"

However, there is this: A sends his regards.

(For example: I met A recently and he sends his regards.)

These seem crude to me. Try:

> A asked me to offer you his regards.
>
> I met A recently, he says he knows you, and that I should offer you his regards.

Comment: "I met A recently and he sends his regards" doesn't sound crude to me at all.